# Subgroups of abelian-by-abelian groups

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, exact-sequence

I know that if $G$ is a finitely generated group and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $H$ is not necessarilly finitely generated.

However, I am asking if this property is true if $G$ is a (finitely generated abelian)-by-(finitely generated abelian) group.

My attempt is the following:

Since $G$ is (finitely generated abelian)-by-(finitely generated abelian), there are two finitely generated abelian groups $A$ and $B$ and a short exact sequence
$$ 1 \rightarrow A \rightarrow G \rightarrow B \rightarrow 1,$$ and let us denote the homomorphism $G \mapsto B$ by $p$.

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Then, that short exact sequence descends to a short exact sequence
$$ 1 \rightarrow A \cap H \rightarrow H \rightarrow p(H) \rightarrow 1.$$

Since $A \cap H$ is a subgroup of $A$ and $A$ is finitely generated abelian, $A\cap H$ is also finitely generated abelian. Because of the same reason, $p(H)$ is finitely generated abelian.

Therefore, $H$ is (finitely generated abelian)-by-(finitely generated abelian). In particular, $H$ is finitely generated.

Is this correct? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes that looks OK! The same argument would work for any class of groups with the property that finitely generated subgroups are also finitely generated. So it works for nilpotent or polycyclic groups.